# Specflow no matching step definition error

Tags: visual-studio, specflow

New to specflow. When i run the below it keeps failing on the Then step as inconclusive. What do i need to do to make this pass?

```
       public virtual void SearchAPICalledWithMissingParameter()
        {
            TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo = new TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioInfo("Search API called with missing parameter", new string[] {
                        "search"});
#line 8
this.ScenarioSetup(scenarioInfo);
#line 9
 testRunner.Given("I call Search API without parameter", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "Given ");
#line 10
 testRunner.When("I get the response back from API", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "When ");
#line 11
 testRunner.Then("API returns <404>", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "Then ");
#line hidden
            this.ScenarioCleanup();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error when i run the test.

```
No matching step definition found for one or more steps.
Using system:
Using TechTalk.SpecFlow;


namespace Mynamespace
{
[Binding]
public class StepDefinitions 
{
[Then(@"API returns(.*)")]
public void ThenAPIReturns(string p0)
{
ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();

}
}
}
```

Comment: You haven't implemented the step? It's still the default implementation which just calls `Pending`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard he's only implemented the Then step which still has the default implementation, but he hasn't even implemented the Given, When, steps.  OP needs to generate the step definitions and add them to the StepDefinitions class.

Comment: @Fran What would i need to do next?

Comment: Generate the other step definitions and then replace the ScenarioContext.Current.Pending() with actual code that does something.

Comment: @Fran Would this work? boolean isTheTextPresent = driver.getPageSource().contains("404");
assertTrue(isTheTextPresent);

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but you need to find a specflow tutorial and work through it.  There is a ton of stuff wrong with question.  you've included the .feature.cs file in your question.  this is autogenerated by specflow and should never be touched.  you need to learn the basics like generating step definitions which are created in a separate cs file all together.  then you actually have to implement the steps.  this requires writing code with either either against a class when doing in process testing or Selenium/HttpClient if performing out of process testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the < and > from the 404. Thats the only illogical thing I can see here.

Another solution could be that there is no space between returns(.*). The step is inconclusive because there is nothing happening. So you need to add an action in the method.

Comment: Would this work with the step definition? boolean isTheTextPresent = driver.getPageSource().contains("404"); assertTrue(isTheTextPresent);

Comment: Could you paste the specflow step? As in, from the feature file?

Comment: Given I call search API without parameter. When i get the response back from the API. Then API returns 404

Comment: The problem could be that your step definition is missing a space: [Then(@"API returns(.*)")] There is no space between returns and (.*)

Comment: In ScenarioContext.Current.Pending(); I need code to replace this. Could i use the following code to check if my API returns 404. boolean isTheTextPresent = driver.getPageSource().contains("404"); assertTrue(isTheTextPresent);

Comment: Yes definetly. Thats the correct way. Even better is: boolean isTheTextPresent = driver.getPageSource().contains(p0); assertTrue(isTheTextPresent);  This way, whichever value you give with specflow, it will check.

Comment: No problem. If my answer suffices, could you mark this answer as correct? Thanks!

Comment: Just one thing, do i need to include anything before the boolean statement?

Comment: Seeing your code, you do not need to add anything. Unless you want to do more than check the 404 in the page source.